# convert list to BigQuery table python

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary, google-bigquery

```
result = {'data1': [1,2], 'data2': [4,5]}
```

I know how to write if I key has single value, but I this case it has list of values how I can iterate. Create table in BigQuery as follows:

```
| data1    | data2          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 4              |
| 2        | 5              |
```

Comment: I would load it into a DataFrame using pandas and then use the info in the following link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-table-dataframe

Comment: To get started, I might check out python's `zip()`, perhaps in conjunction with the `items()` of that dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to same problem and I couldnt find a solution, so what I did(All our DB's are managed as service in our code) is the following:

I am fetching the table id, then using `get_table(table_id)`  .

Now I am sending the `table._properties['schema']['fields']`  with the list data to a function that convert it into Json

```
def __Convert_Data_To_Json(self,data,table_fields):       
       if not(len(table_fields)==len(data[0])):
          raise CannotCreateConnectionError(CANNOT_CREATE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE % str('Data length doesnt match table feild list'))
       for row in data:
          dataset={}
          i=0
          for col in row:                           
              if col==None:
                dataset[list(table_fields[i].values())[0]  ]=None
              else:
                  dataset[list(table_fields[i].values())[0]  ]=str(col)
              i+=1
          self.__rows_to_insert.append(dataset)
```

and then using `insert_rows_json`